# Installing Azure SDK for C++ in a docker container

Tags: c++, azure, docker, azure-sdk

I would like to know how I may install azure c++ sdk in a docker container. I need it for a C++ services that downloads and processes files in Azure blob storage. Personally, I feel like the container will become too large and also the installation is kind of complex compare to the popular:

```
...
// Docker file
        
RUN git clone https://github.com/blah/bla.git \
    && cd blah && mkdir -p build \
    && cd build \
    && cmake .. \
    && cmake --build . --target install 
...
```

I have read the installation guide [here](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-cpp/) and [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-cpp) but after following the whole installation procedure in my development environment (Centos 8), cmake fails to find the
`azure-storage-blobs-cpp` even after adding the `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=[path to vcpkg repo]/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake` flag correctly.

Is there an alternative or straight forward way like in the above snippet for installing the SDK in my development environment and then in a Linux based container for deployment?

Comment: You can refer this open issue in GitHub :https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-cpp/issues/3005 & can refer this link may it helps https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/developing-linux-c-applications-with-azure-docker-containers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While researching, I came across this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-cpp/issues/2955). Here, [janbernloehr](https://github.com/janbernloehr) references to a library called `azure-storage-cpplite` which I searched and tried. Yes, it solves my problem!

First, it's easy to install locally or in a docker container. Dependencies: OpenSSL, libuuid and libcurl.

```
RUN git clone https://github.com/azure/azure-storage-cpplite.git \
    && cd azure-storage-cpplite && mkdir -p build && cd build \ 
    && cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    && cmake --build . \ 
    && cmake --build . --target install
```

Secondly, it's simple to include the library in your CMake project.

```
set(Headers
  include/your-file.h
)

set(Sources
  src/your-file.cpp
  )

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -lm -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib")

set(CURL_LIBRARY "-lcurl") 
find_package(CURL REQUIRED) 

add_library(appname STATIC ${Sources} ${Headers})

target_compile_features(appname PUBLIC cxx_std_17)

target_include_directories(appname PUBLIC ${CURL_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(appname ${CURL_LIBRARIES} azure-storage-lite -lcrypto -luuid)
```

Thirdly, it is lightweight, with close to 30MB in download size which is OK for a docker container.

If it wasn't for this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-cpp/issues/2955) I wouldn't have found the cpplite SDK. I don't know why it's a hidden gem. If you know anything let us know.